# SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) automatically stop

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, sql-server-agent

I'm encountering a problem on Microsoft SQL Server. SQL Server Agent is not running, when I tried to start it and refresh the services.msc the SQL Server Agent is not running anymore. When I see the logs on event viewer. There are no errors but a message "SQLServerAgent service successfully stopped"

Here is the log.

```
SQLServerAgent service successfully started

SQLServerAgent service successfully stopped.
```

Answer (score 6):

SQLEXPRESS does not include the SQL Server Agent aspect of the product.

You need to have SQL Server Standard Edition (or greater) to get the SQL Server Agent functionality.

That said, there may be other ways to achieve the results you desire.  You could build a simple .NET app or PowerShell script to execute your query or stored procedure, and schedule that to execute via Windows own task scheduler.  It is in many ways not as robust as SQL Server Agent, but it is also not as restrictive (you're running under a Windows process as opposed to SQL Server, so you have more options as to how the application may work).

Comment: There's some (limited) information here. It seems that SQL Agent is indeed useless for Express editions. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/351806/sql-express-rc0-installs-sql-agent-service-for-no-apparent-reason